# Plotting 3D cone using gnuplot of user data file

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file in x,y,z and want to plot a 3D cone using the data. I tried splot but it is giving only last point circle. My data file is in following format :

```
X   y   z 
0  18  18 
10  59  59     
20  80  80
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance
-Abhi

Comment: Is that really your datafile format?  (do the blank lines really exist?)

Comment: no blank lines are there in datafile...sorry for late reply - Abhi

Comment: I've updated your question to reflect the way the data actually looks.  Feel free to edit it to correct if I've done anything incorrectly.  As a side note, you might want to add a little more explanation about how the datafile is generated, or what it contains.  As it is, it's hard to really interpret anything from just 3 points.

Comment: Thanks for updating data. Data is generated through Fresnel's Equation. This equation is used in seismic domain to get fresnel radius for a process called Migration in geophysics.

Comment: I'm a little familiar with the Fresnel Equations via optics.  Maybe it will be instructive for me to just post a small script showing you how you can create a datafile that gnuplot can use to plot a cone ... We can work from there.

Answer (score 1):

At this point, I think it might be easier to show a simple script that can be used to generate data in a format that gnuplot can use to plot a cone:

I'll use python for 2 reasons.  First, I know it pretty well, and second, it reads pretty much like pseudo-code, so it should be pretty clear what is happening even if you don't know python.

```
import math
h = 2
points_u = map(float,range(-h,h+1)) #[-2.,-1.,0.,1.,2.]

NTHETA = 12    #number of points in theta for the cone
dtheta = 2.*math.pi/NTHETA
points_theta = [dtheta*i for i in range(NTHETA+1)] #list of points in theta

with open('data.txt','w') as fout:  #open an output file for the data
    for theta in points_theta:
        for u in points_u:
            #This is how to plot a cone parametrically
            #Here I unravel the cone into it's x-y-z components
            #The important part is that within the inner loop,
            #we're writing data along a single theta.  In other words,
            #within the inner loop, we write a single straight line which
            #is on the surface of the cone.
            x = (h-u)/h*math.cos(theta)
            y = (h-u)/h*math.sin(theta)
            z = u
            fout.write('%f %f %f\n'%(x,y,z))

        #After the inner loop, you need to insert a blank line to let gnuplot know
        #that the particular "scan" is over and it is supposed to start a new "scan"
        #After all is said and done, gnuplot will connect the points.
        fout.write('\n')
```

Now this generates a datafile `data.txt`.  To plot this datafile in gnuplot, you can simply do:

```
set surface
#set hidden3d  #This makes the object "non-transparent"
splot 'data.txt' using 1:2:3 with lines
```